# How to get instructor data for course?

Tags: angular

I have detail page of one course. There is the title, image and description about this course. Below i have instructor box with avatar and full name, that show who created this course.

My question is How can i get the avatar and full name of this course ?

```
course-details component ts

import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ICourse, IUser } from '../../../../../core/models';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-about-course',
    template: `
        <div>
            <div class='mt-14'>
                <h1 class='text-xl font-medium description-section text-darkgray'>Course title</h1>
                <p class='text-2sm font-normal text-darkgray description-p mt-6'>
                   {{course.title}}
                   {{course.description}}
                </p>
            </div>
                <div>
                  <app-instructor-box [instructors]='instructor'></app-instructor-box>
                </div>
        </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./about-course.component.scss'],
})
export class AboutCourseComponent {
    @Input() course: ICourse;
    @Input() instructor: IUser;
}
```

With "@Input() course: ICourse" i get course data from server

```
instructor component ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { IUser } from '../../../../../core/models';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-instructor-box',
    template: `
        <div class='instructor-box lg:instructor-box-lg'>
            <h1 class='hidden lg:block text-xl font-medium text-darkgray'>Instructor:</h1>
            <div class='grid sm:flex items-center justify-content md:justify-content-md text-center lg:text-left'>
                <div class='mt-5'><img class='instructor-img lg:instructor-img-lg' [src]='instructors.avatarUrl' alt=''>
                </div>
                <div class='info-instructor sm:info-instructor-lg'>
                    <h1 class='text-xl font-medium text-darkgray instr-title'>{{instructors.firstName}} {{instructors.lastName}}</h1>
                    <p class='text-sm font-normal text-regulargray instr-profesion'
                       *ngFor='let authorProfessions of instructors.professions'>{{authorProfessions.name}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./instructor-box.component.scss'],
})
export class InstructorBoxComponent {
    @Input() instructors: IUser;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with the code?

Comment: When i try to get data from server for instructors i have error like “instructors.avaratUrl of undefined ” and for all data like images, full name and professions

Comment: then edit the question to add the code that pulls data from the server

Comment: You may be rendering the component before actually getting response from server. Try setting default value for instructor, so it has **something** to render while waiting for the real data, or use *optional chaining* operator like `<img [src]="instructor?.avatarUrl">`

Answer (score 0):

You get instructor as an @input ( @Input() course: ICourse; ), and then, when you do

```
<app-instructor-box [instructors]='instructor'...
```

then are passing it to app-instructor-box as an @input as well ( @Input() instructors: IUser;, inside app-instructor-box).

I only used @input at 1 level, not 2 (for more complicated data interchange, I use a service as "store"). Maybe, it should be some kind of "delay" in get the value.

Maybe, if you try something like this:

1. Inside the HTML template of app-instructor-box, put all the references to 'instructors'  with an '?', as this:

```
instructors?.avatarUrl
```

2. Put a div or ngcontainer wrapping your code, with an *ngIf="instructors", like this:

```
 template: `
        <div class='instructor-box lg:instructor-box-lg'>
            <h1 class='hidden lg:block text-xl font-medium text-darkgray'>Instructor:</h1>

<div *ngIf="instructors">
            <div class='grid sm:flex items-center justify-content md:justify-content-md text-center lg:text-left'>
                <div class='mt-5'><img class='instructor-img lg:instructor-img-lg' [src]='instructors.avatarUrl' alt=''>
                </div>
                <div class='info-instructor sm:info-instructor-lg'>
                    <h1 class='text-xl font-medium text-darkgray instr-title'>{{instructors.firstName}} {{instructors.lastName}}</h1>
                    <p class='text-sm font-normal text-regulargray instr-profesion'
                       *ngFor='let authorProfessions of instructors.professions'>{{authorProfessions.name}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>

        </div>
    `,
```

If you don't give more info, it's the only help I can provide, just a try.